# Application filters redirection loop

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I'm new to servlet filters, and i'm facing a problem in my project while using filters. 
I've two filters, AuthenticationFilter and AuthorizationFilter. They apply to /user/* pages in my netbeans project, where I've created an index page for every type of user. The first filter checks so that the user pages are accessed only by authenticated users. The second filter then checks if the requested ulr is valid for that user  and redirects accordingly. Below you may find the doFilter method for each filter:

Authentication Filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    HttpServletRequest req = ( HttpServletRequest )request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = ( HttpServletResponse ) response;
    HttpSession ses = req.getSession( false );

    User user = ( User )req.getSession().getAttribute( "user" );
    //String url = req.getRequestURI();

    if( user == null  )
        resp.sendRedirect( req.getContextPath()+ "/index.xhtml" );
    else
        chain.doFilter ( request, response );
}
```

Authorization Filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException 
{

    HttpServletRequest req = ( HttpServletRequest )request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = ( HttpServletResponse ) response;
    HttpSession ses = req.getSession( false );
    User user = ( User )req.getSession().getAttribute( "user" );
    String url = req.getRequestURI();
    Role role = ( Role ) user.getRole();

    if( role != null )
    {
        int roleId = role.getRoleId();
        switch( roleId )
        {
            case 13:
            {
                resp.sendRedirect( req.getContextPath()+ "/user/studentIndex.xhtml" );

            };break;
            case 12:
            {
                resp.sendRedirect( req.getContextPath()+ "/user/instructorIndex.xhtml" );

            };break;
            case 11:
            {
                resp.sendRedirect( req.getContextPath()+ "/user/staffIndex.xhtml" );
            };break;
        }
    }
    else
         chain.doFilter ( request, response );


}
```

Clearly, the sendRedirect method in the authorization filter triggers the Authentication filter, since they both apply to /user/* pages, and I end up in an **infinite loop**!!!! I know that putting Authentication and Authorization logic in the same filter would solve my problem, however is there any way to tackle it by keeping both filters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you redirecting from the `Authentication` filter? Combining both of them into a single filter would do a better job.

Comment: #BalusC in the bean i'm calling the respective dao to get the transient object(User). If there is no user, the user object will be null, so i redirect to /index page where the user can log in.

Comment: @Tiny thnx for the reply, above you may find my comment. Moreover combining them to the same filter still causes a problem, i've just tried. Since each index page is located in /user/ directory and the filter applies to /user/*, the redirection to the appropriate index page will trigger again the filter.

Comment: @BalusC Thnx, my comment above..

Comment: That's a problem of another side. The current question is not about that problem. If you mapped a filter to the URL pattern `/user/*`, the filter would be called whenever a request matches the pattern as obvious. Separate this filter from the rest of the application and map the filter to another URL pattern that matches only for an authentication/authorization request. Or alternatively, use a Servlet (or if you happened to use JSF, use a managed bean) for the same.

Comment: @Tiny, i'm using JSF, however i want to filter an authenticated user, ex a student, accessing instructor page directly from the browser link. Anyway, i think I'll play around with placing my pages on different folders and implement filters accordingly.

Comment: Let those pages be there as they are. Just map the filter to another URL pattern by making a new URL pattern available, if it does not exist already. Essentially, authorization system works somewhat differently. You should put resources in separate directories according to authorities in your application. For instance, student related pages should be kept in a directory named `student`, instructor related pages in a directory named `instructor`, staff related pages in a directory named `staff`, administrator related pages in a directory named `admin` etc.

Comment: And then authenticate and authorize a user based on his/her authority/role and redirect the user to his/her section accordingly using `requestURL` and let him/her access only that section.

Comment: @Tiny, thnx. Most probably i'll do that.